# I want to add the results of a Fetch request from a Core Data entity into an Array

Tags: arrays, core-data, fetch

I am using the following code to retrieve rows from an entity in my Core Data DB. I am able to successfully fetch the data. I can also access the rows of the entity and add it to an array. However when I try using the array 'outside' the do { } enclosure, I am only able to read the last array item value. Please assist me.

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

```
    guard let appDelegate =
      UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext =
      appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T01_test_results>(entityName: "T01_test_results")
    
    //3
    do {
        let tests  = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for test in tests {
            
            testItem.max_number = test.c01_max_number!
            testItem.results = test.c01_results!
            testItem.test_date = test.c01_test_date!
            testItem.timesTable = test.c01_timesTable!
            print("In Loop -- \(testItem.timesTable)")
            testItem.total_correct = test.c01_total_correct!
            testItem.total_questions = test.c01_total_questions!
            testArray.append(testItem)
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

     print("Single element -> \(testArray[3].timesTable)")

}
```

Comment: On each iteration of the loop, you update the values of the `testItem` and append it to your array - but it is the same `testItem` each time.  Hence all elements of the array are the same `testItem` and will all have the values assigned in the last iteration of the loop.  You need to create a new `testItem` on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks a mil! Made the change and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be solved. I was using a Class based object to store the retrieved values. Changed this to a struct based type and seems to be working fine!